# Is it possible to call TidSMTP.Connect once and then from threads call TidSMTP.Send?

Tags: delphi, indy

I am writing an app that sends e-mail messages using Indy.

Every message is sent by a thread.

Currently I am connecting to `TidSMTP` inside the thread, so for sending 10 mails, I need 10 threads and I connect 10 times.

Is it safe (which are the drawbacks?) of having a single `TidSMTP` (outside of the thread), call `Connect` once and then call `TidSMTP.Send` inside the thread?

Will `TidSMTP` manage thing correctly?

Note: the idea is to avoid to connect every time (if possible), in case of many emails to be sent it could be an advantage. (does it makes sense to get worried for this, or calling `Connect` in every thread is pefectly ok?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use only 1 thead in which you have a TIdSMTP and a TList in which you store TIdMessage's and after each send you free the TIdMessage from the list, in this case you avoid overhead and keep it simple.
What if you want to send 200 e-mails, well if you start 200 threads then your application will use over 200 Mb only for those 200 threads not to mention that there can be problems starting that many threads in your application.
Bottom line add a TList in which you temporarily store prepared TIdMessages and inside the thread a while loop that will check if the list has any messages to send, if it has then grab, send and remove from list.

Comment: yes, it is  a good suggestion. My idea is to start simple and have only one thread at a time, in this case your suggestino is 100% logic. But then I want to have 3 parallel threads (one that sends no mails with no attachemnts, another that sends smal attachments ones, another that sends bigger attachemnts ones). Anyway with your suggestion I could simply create 1 smtp per thread. Thanks.

Comment: your welcome, yes you can have 3 threads or even 20 if you wish, each individual thread with a different scope, but NOT 50, 100, 200, etc. threads, if you wish to send a e-mail to X nr. of people then have a look at BCC(blind carbon copy) so that they won't see other e-mail addresses that received the e-mail.

Comment: @user193655: Why don't use a TQueue for that, I think it's more accurate.  You may have one SMTP component and one Queue component per thread... suggesting TList instead of TQueue is the only reason I don't upvote @Dorin answer.

Comment: Thanks for the extra comment, I am aware TQueue, or the generic counterpart is the best choice. Anyway I realized that I can control failure better if I restart the thread from time to time, so every thread will take care of sending a number of messages and then it will terminate. So every thread will have an internal queue, while I will "delegate" to the DB to keep the real message queue.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can call Connect() in one thread and then call Send() in other threads.  However, you would have to serialize access to Send(), otherwise the sending threads can overlap each other and corrupt the SMTP communication.  Dorin's suggestion to move all of the SMTP traffic to a single thread with a queue is the best choice.  However, the queue itself needs to be accessed in a thread-safe manner, so using a plain TList or TQueue by itself it not good enough.  Either use TThreadList (or Indy's own TIdThreadSafeList) instead of TList, or wrap the TQueue with a separate TCriticalSection.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning those components i was not aware of, anyway i found an acceptable solution that works for me now.